# Heroku does not really seem support Python and Django on Windows

Tags: python, django, windows, heroku

Heroku seems to have a dependency on Gunicorn when it comes to Python / Django apps. Gunicorn is not supported on Windows. Has anybody had success or know of a work around?

My app runs fine but not under Heroku or Heroku local

Error:

```
...site-packages\gunicorn\util.py", line 9, in <module>
import fcntl
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'fcntl'
Exited with exit code null
```

Comment: With your choice of OS you have chosen the painful way. Is there any hard requirement for Windows?

Comment: Thanks for the response Klaus. Yes, most of my work for a long time is under windows and the only system I have. Just trying to expand my experience into new horizons,

Answer (score 1):

It seems unfair to blame Heroku for this. *Gunicorn* doesn't support Windows. Heroku has nothing to do with Windows.

There are other WSGI web servers that may work. For example, uWSGI [has documentation for running on Heroku](https://uwsgi-docs.readthedocs.io/en/latest/tutorials/heroku_python.html).

A quick summary:

- Make sure that `uwsgi` and `werkzeug` are in your `requirements.txt` or `Pipfile` / `Pipfile.lock` and that these files are tracked by Git
- Create and track a `uwsgi.ini` file containing something like

  ```
  [uwsgi]
  http-socket = :$(PORT)
  master = true
  processes = 4
  die-on-term = true
  module = werkzeug.testapp:test_app
  memory-report = true
  ```

  making sure to set the `module` appropriately for your application.
- Update your `Procfile` to contain

  ```
  web: uwsgi uwsgi.ini
  ```

Make sure it works with [`heroku local`](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/heroku-local#run-your-app-locally-using-the-heroku-local-command-line-tool-start-your-app-locally), then push to Heroku.